# Find entities which have more than one relation of a certain type

Tags: postgresql

Given this Postgres schema:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS asset_category;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS asset;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category;


CREATE TABLE asset (
    "id" BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IDX_id" ON asset (id);

CREATE TABLE category (
    "id" BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "type" TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IDX_id" ON category (id);

CREATE TABLE asset_category (
    "asset_id" BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "category_id" BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_asset_id" FOREIGN KEY ("asset_id") REFERENCES "asset" ("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_category_id" FOREIGN KEY ("category_id") REFERENCES "category" ("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
    UNIQUE (asset_id, category_id)
);
```

and some demo data

```sql
INSERT INTO asset (id, "name") VALUES(1, 'Awesome Asset');
INSERT INTO asset (id, "name") VALUES(2, 'Great Asset');
INSERT INTO asset (id, "name") VALUES(3, 'Super Asset');
INSERT INTO asset (id, "name") VALUES(4, 'Best Asset');
INSERT INTO asset (id, "name") VALUES(5, 'Hilarious Asset');

INSERT INTO category (id, "name", "type") VALUES(1, 'Awesome Category', NULL);
INSERT INTO category (id, "name", "type") VALUES(2, 'Great Category', 'folder');
INSERT INTO category (id, "name", "type") VALUES(3, 'Super Category', 'folder');
INSERT INTO category (id, "name", "type") VALUES(4, 'Best Category', NULL);
INSERT INTO category (id, "name", "type") VALUES(5, 'Hilarious Category', NULL);

INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(2, 4);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(3, 2);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(3, 3);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(4, 5);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(5, 1);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(5, 2);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(5, 3);
```

How can I create an SQL query that returns all assets which have more than one category of type `folder` associated?

Here we can see, that this is the case:

```
SELECT *
FROM asset a

LEFT JOIN asset_category ac ON a.id = ac.asset_id
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id = ac.category_id AND c.type = 'folder'

WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL
```

Asset `3` and `5` have more than one.

How can I identify those with a query?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it with

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM asset a
JOIN (
  SELECT asset_id
  FROM asset_category ac
  JOIN category c ON ac.category_id = c.id
  WHERE c.type = 'folder'
  GROUP BY asset_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) sub ON a.id = sub.asset_id;
```